# Solr Jetty crashes without reason

Tags: solr

Every now and then my Solr instance is crashing. It runs in a Jetty container and the logs only show a valid request before it crashes.

I use Solr with PHP and filegetcontents() to retrieve data from my index. It is a fairly well hitted installation ( ~ 10 req/s ) but Solr should be able to cope with that I thought.

Any ideas?

xms setting: 512 Mb
xmx setting: 1024 Mb

I cannot find a single crash entry in the logs / dumps. Or am I missing a log file? (I checked the jetty log file)

Comment: can you share some info, like what's the RAM settings, RAM usage before the crash, cache situation? Good idea in such cases is to set detailedDump=true

Comment: RAM settings: xmx: 1024Mb, xms: 512 Mb

Comment: how big is the index? You could check the solr cache values as well: sizes, evictions and hitRatios.

Comment: I did, and that would show up in the logs right? Or am I missing a log file

Comment: cache stats show on the solr admin page. detailedDump would show in the logs